# Android 12 save image from gallery

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-12, android-13

Why i dont need permissions for saving a image from gallery? I dont acccept "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", but nevertheless i can store the image to my private app folder. I want to use permissions for comparing the "old" api with the new photopicker api.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},Read_Permissions);
        }

single.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SINGLE_PICTURE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Snackbar failsnackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "failure", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            failsnackbar.show();
            return;
        }
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        switch (requestCode) {

            case SINGLE_PICTURE:
                if (data.getData() != null) {

                    Uri mImageUri = data.getData();

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
///other stuff

private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mypath=new File(directory,timeStamp+".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
 image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: It is unclear what you have in mind if you talk about saving from gallery. Please rephrase. Tell better what you do and want. Questions about saving to memory are common.